# Powershell - Finding an undefined series of characters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find an undefined series of characters and replace them with a defined set via powershell. The particularly troublesome line of script involves altering the xml manifest of an Android project:

```
(get-content "AndroidManifest.xml") | 
   foreach { $_ -replace "@drawable/*_icon", "@drawable/$icon_icon"} | 
   set-content "AndroidManifest.xml"
```

The idea of this line is that it retrieves the content, searches and replaces the icon string (replacing the existing icon name with that represented by $icon) and then passes this back into the file.

Unfortunately, when executed this doesn't appear to actually do its job, and the string is just not changing. The existing string is changeable, so no values can be inputted (hence the wildcard).

Can anybody suggest a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the regular expression you're using isn't quite correct. The `*` modifier matches zero or more of the previous character, so `/*_icon` matches zero or more forward slashes followed by `_icon`.

Second, in your replacement string, what you match is going to be replaced with the value of the `$icon_icon` variable.  You need to wrap the `$icon` variable as an expression, `$($icon)_icon` or a string format, `"@drawable/{0}_icon" -f $icon`.  I prefer string formats.

Put it all together and you get:

```
 $_ -replace "@drawable/(.*?)_icon", ("@drawable/{0}_icon" -f $icon)
```

Comment: +1. However, $_ -replace "@drawable/(.*?)_icon", "@drawable/$($icon)_icon" would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Replace $icon_icon with $($icon)_icon in your script.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Could you show a relevant excerpt of your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: The relevant line from the manifest is `<application android:icon="@drawable/X_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="cmApp" android:debuggable="true">` where X is the original icon name. Here I am trying to pick out the string with @drawable to replace X with $icon.

I wish I could be more specific here but this is not my XML, it belongs to my employer and I am simply trying to streamline the build process.